# React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback error occurs

Tags: reactjs

The error below sometimes occurs I don't know why. Every code seems to work but only an error occurs.

> React Hook "useEffect" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

import { useAuthContext } from 'src/contexts/Auth'

import { brandRepository } from 'src/repositories/BrandRepository'

export default function TestBrand() {
  const [brands, setBrands] = useState<any[]>()

  const { currentUser } = useAuthContext()

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!currentUser) return
    useEffect(() => {
      brandRepository.list(currentUser.id).then(async (docs: any[]) => {
        if(!docs) return
        await setBrands(docs)
      })
    }, [])
    }, [currentUser])

  if(!currentUser) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  return (
    <div>test</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You don't need (and indeed can't use) nested `useEffect`s.

Comment: You're trying to call `useEffect` inside another `useEffect`. This will not work. What behavior are you trying to achieve?

Comment: OMG. I have really missed it, thanks guys!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in `useEffect`  you are making a network request for one time if the `currentUser` exists. In this case you don't need 2 `useEffect`. if can do it like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(!currentUser) return
    
      brandRepository.list(currentUser.id).then(async (docs: any[]) => {
        if(!docs) return
        await setBrands(docs)
      })
    
 }, [currentUser])
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use useEffect inside another useEffect. Try using both the hooks separately as it forbids the rules of hooks. Better don't use the second useEffect as I do not see any specific use of it. Refer this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 1):

You cant call useEffect or other hooks inside a function or CB you can only call hooks inside Function component
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

> Blockquote
> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function, before any early returns. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls